# Преобразование из jquery в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Начиналось всё с мой метки jquery2javascript. Потом прилетела в голову iдея - написать программку - которая получает код, в котором используется jquery, а отдаёт код на pure js. Однако вытекает

**Вопрос 1** *кто-нибудь делал похожие штуки? Мне не попалось, но всё же, вдруг кто-нибудь видел?*

Заодно, **Вопрос 2** прав ли я, что превращённый код будет работать быстрее? Ну смотрите:

До преобразования:

```
//<js библиотека>
function dualalert(text) {
alert(text);
alert(text);
}
//</js библиотека>

dualalert("meow!");
```

После:

```
alert("meow!");
alert("meow!");
```

Вроде второй код более быстрее первого. Так и будет работать преобразовалка. А если:

```
$('#elem')
```

превратить в

```
document.getElementById('elem')
```

то это вообще супер оптимизация, т.к. не придётся парсеру работать - впереди **#** или **.** Правда наверняка в jquery библиотеке для этого используется кеширование, но никто не помешает его перекопировать. Так что вопрос в том, прав ли я, **что превращённый код будет работать быстрее?**

Ну и **Вопрос 3** - по какой системе лучше строить эту штуку? Варианта два:

1. вручную сказать проге, что $('#elem') менять на document.getElementById('elem'), а $('.elem') на document.getElementsByClass('elem')
2. давать проге jquery.js. Прога будет видеть в коде

   dualalert("meow!");

Искать в jquery *function dualalert(smth)*, находить

```
function dualalert(text) {
alert(text);
alert(text);
}
```

Копировать:

```
alert("meow!");
alert("meow!");
```

И вставлять это, вместо dualalert("meow!") в преобразуемом коде.

**Вопрос 4** Можно ли назвать это компиляцией? Вики гласит:

> Компиляция - трансляция программы, составленной на
> исходном языке высокого уровня, в
> эквивалентную программу на
> низкоуровневом языке, близком
> машинному коду (абсолютный код,
> объектный модуль, иногда на язык
> ассемблера).[2][3][4] Входной
> информацией для компилятора (исходный
> код) является описание алгоритма или
> программа на проблемно-ориентированном
> языке, а на выходе компилятора —
> эквивалентное описание алгоритма на
> машинно-ориентированном языке
> (объектный код).

Её вроде здесь вообще нельзя верить, ведь из dart в js тоже называли компиляцией. В нашем случее идёт преобразование чего-то высшего уровня в более низкий. Слово язык подставить нельзя - язык остаётся один и тот-же. Потому-то сомневаюсь.

p.s. конечно чу-чуть  холиваром попахивает, но только 2ой подвопрос, и то не сильно. Так что просьба не закрывать вопрос. На крайний случай, если вдруг холивар разрастётся, то можно будет просто вычеркнуть 2ой подвопрос...

Comment: сколько можно повторять jquery это и есть javascript

Comment: @eicto покажите где я это отрицал

Comment: в заголовке вопроса.

Comment: @eicto ну как это тогда назвать? Да, при использовании jquery можно использовать и javascript, но без <script src="jquery.js"> jquery коды не заработают

Comment: ну да, если объект не инициализироать/написать то его методы недоступны. как называть это не знаю, т.к. это неделанье, практически по К.К.

Comment: сколько миллисекунд сэкономить хотите?

Comment: преобразование из курицы в яйцо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1** Смысла нет, т.к. те части jQuery что действительно полезны собственно и выполняются вполне оптимально. Например если вы все

$('.myclass').on('myevent','.my_subclass');

раскроете до того что описано в events.js в исходнике jQuery, и при этом по 500раз, у вас просто начальный парсинг будет зачастую дольше чем всё исполнение.

**2** Да быстрее, ещё быстрее  наверное window.id (не рекомендую). Я не смотрел туда давно, но уже давно существует `document.querySelectorAll()`, думаю jQuery использует его, когда доступен.

**3** См пункт 1 - строить не надо

**4** Ну если у вас jQuery это не javascript то да. на самом деле нет. наверное cofeescript будет ближе, но я его не щупал особо, по крайней мере синтаксис у него не js.

если  вам действительно нечем занятьcя - портируйте jquery на C в виде npm модуля чтобы в node.js быстро работал.

Answer (score 1):

вычеркните лучше все вопросы пока не заминусовали...
если говорить предметно, то

```
 2.Код выполняется быстрее так как не выделяется память под функцию
 3.Jquery делает тоже самое, просто предоставляет удобный интерфейс
 4. Нет, JS это интерпретатор, а то что вы делаете, это максимум рефракторинг, и то с      очень большой натяжкой.
```